Batch call in chunks to post data in bulk in Fiori
I am trying to upload an excel with having ~3000 line items. To upload that, I am trying to have a batch call and posting data in chunks of 100 line items. The batch calls are getting successful. The issue is that every batch call enters into the 'success' function even before the call is executed. Even if a batch call is failing, it enters into the 'success' function. I am not able to identify whenever the batch is failing. The success function return me nothing. The 'response' parameter is undefined and the 'odata' parameter returns empty. Please help!
postExcelToBackend: function (selectedData) {
            // selectedData parameter has the complete excel data

            // Loop through the selected items
            var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("myODataModel");
            var aBatchOperations = [];
            var chunkSize = 100;
            // Track the status of each chunk (success or failure) with failed row numbers
            var chunkStatus = [];

            // Maintain a separate mapping for row numbers
            var rowMapping = [];


            var that = this;

            function submitChunk(chunk, chunkIndex) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var aBatchOperations = [];
                    chunk.forEach(function (oItem, index) {
                        // Create a batch change entry

                            var oPayload = that.createPayload(oItem);
                        rowMapping.push({ payload: oPayload, rowIndex: chunkIndex * chunkSize + index + 1 });

                        // Create a batch change entry
                        aBatchOperations.push(oModel.createEntry("/AuctionProcessSet", { properties: oPayload })); 
                    });


                    var batchGroupId = "batchGroup" + chunkIndex;
                    oModel.setDeferredGroups([batchGroupId]);

                    
                    oModel.setUseBatch(true);
                    oModel.submitChanges({
                        groupId: batchGroupId,
                        success: function (oData, response) {
              // Everytime the batch enters here even before the call is successful.
                            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Batch operation successful!");
                            chunkStatus.push({ chunkIndex: chunkIndex + 1, status: "success" });
                            resolve();
                        },
                        error: function (oError) {
                            var failedRowIndices = [];
                            var failedRowDetails = [];
        
                            // Parse the error response to identify which entries failed
                            if (oError && oError.responseText) {
                                try {
                                    var oErrorResponse = JSON.parse(oError.responseText);
                                    if (oErrorResponse.error && oErrorResponse.error.innererror) {
                                        var batchResponses = oErrorResponse.error.innererror.errordetails || [];
        
                                        // Check each error detail to identify which entries failed
                                        batchResponses.forEach(function (detail) {
                                            if (detail.target) {
                                                var errorTargetMatch = detail.target.match(/\((\d+)\)/); // Match pattern to identify index
                                                if (errorTargetMatch) {
                                                    var payloadIndex = parseInt(errorTargetMatch[1]); // Extract payload index from the response
                                                    failedRowIndices.push(payloadIndex);
                                                    failedRowDetails.push({
                                                        rowIndex: rowMapping[payloadIndex].rowIndex, // Use mapping to get the row index
                                                        errorMessage: detail.message
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                } catch (e) {
                                    console.error("Failed to parse error response", e);
                                }
                            }
        
                            sap.m.MessageToast.show(`Error in batch operation for chunk ${chunkIndex + 1}. Check console for failed rows.`);
                            chunkStatus.push({ chunkIndex: chunkIndex + 1, status: "failure", failedRows: failedRowDetails });
                            reject(oError);
                        }
                    });


                });

            }

            async function processChunks() {
                var flag = 0;
                for (let i = 0; i < selectedData.length; i += chunkSize) {
                    const chunk = selectedData.slice(i, i + chunkSize); // Create a chunk
                    try {
                        await submitChunk(chunk, i / chunkSize); // Wait for the current chunk to finish
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error("Failed to submit chunk:", error);
                        break; // Stop processing on error
                    }
                }


                var failedChunks = chunkStatus.filter(status => status.status === "failure");
                if (failedChunks.length > 0) {
                    console.warn("The following chunks failed:", failedChunks);
                    sap.m.MessageBox.error(`Batch operation failed for ${failedChunks.length} chunk(s). Check console for details.`);
        
                    // Log failed rows
                    failedChunks.forEach(chunk => {
                        chunk.failedRows.forEach(row => {
                            console.error(`Failed Excel Row: ${row.rowIndex} | Error: ${row.errorMessage}`);
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("All chunks processed successfully!");
                }
            }

            

            // Start processing the chunks
            processChunks();


        }


Quick question: Do you know about the Spreadsheet Importer? This way you don't have to reinvent the wheel.
